# subgroups containing $T(3,K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $K$ be a field which is algebraically closed. $T(3,K)\subset GL(3,K)$ denotes the subgroup of upper-triangular matrix. Can we decide all subgroups of $GL(3,K)$ which contains $T(3,K)$?

Comment: Assuming you mean closed subgroups, then these are the so-called standard parabolic subgroups, and yes, they are parametrized by subsets of the set of simple roots.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found this question in Humphrey's linear algebraic group, exo 21.7. Actually we can prove that all such groups are closed (but I don't know how to prove it). Is there any more elementary method to decide all such subgroups because until that section, Humphrey hasn't talked about root system?

Comment: So in the end, there are some obvious choices for such subgroups, and the hard part is proving that there are no others. How to do that from only the basics is something I have unfortunately completely forgotten.